# Azure SQL query performance changed

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have been running a query on Azure SQL database and the same query is now taking 10 times longer - 4mins up to 40. The datasets are the same and even with ramping up the DTU's, the query time barely changes.

Are there any things I can do to either reset the database to how it was performing or any tips to help out.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have query store enabled? If so look at the query history and see if the execution plan changed

Comment: In ssms, using live query execution plan, see where it is getting stuck/data transfer is slow.

Comment: Use Force Last Good Plan. Enable that feature on the Automatic Tuning option. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning